# .Net Core 3.1 Linq to Entities - How to concat strings in where clause

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, .net-core, linq-to-entities

I have a user table with [FirstName] and [LastName] columns.
I'm trying to build a search function that returns users that meet one of the criteria below:

- FirstName == myPattern, or
- LastName == myPattern, or
- FirstName LastName == myPattern

For example, if I have the following users in my database:

- Jack One
- Jack Two
- Jack Three

I'd like the function to return all of them when the input is **Jack**, but only return Jack One when the input is **Jack One**

I currently have the following code:

```
var users = context.User.Where(x => x.FirstName == pattern 
            || x.LastName == pattern
            || x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName == pattern)
```

But this does not work as the it gets translated to the following query in MySQL

```
...WHERE (`p`.`firstName` = 'Jack One') OR (`p`.`lastName` = 'Jack One')) OR (((`p`.`firstName` + ' ') + `p`.`lastName`) = 'Jack One')
```

It does not work because I believe we need to use CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) if I want to concat multiple strings in MySQL.

I tried using the following .NET functions but they cannot be translated to sql (The LINQ expression ... could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync())

- string.Join(' ', firstName, lastName)
- string.Concat(firstName, " ", lastName)

How can I achieve this in .NET CORE 3.1 **without** pulling all data into memory and evaluating it in client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an case of Linq translating the query in a manner you aren't predicting.

Going from memory and no IDE on hand to check it, but give this a shot. If you split the full name on the space first, you can use the values in your query.

```cs
// returns an array based on the patter, if it can be split
var names = pattern.Split(" ");

// then use the array elements in the query
var users = context.User.Where(x => x.FirstName == pattern 
    || x.LastName == pattern
    || (x.FirstName == names[0] && x.LastName == names[1]));
```

The last OR condition of the query should then evaulate the 2 new elements in the names array, that was created off the pattern

Comment: Thanks for your idea. While this works in most cases, it won't work for users with white-space in firstname or lastname (e.g. "Jack Bob One"). This could happen for users with middle names or non-english names.

Comment: Good point. Working through all cases would cause some errors. Maybe set up a stored procedure on the DB side to check the value against a view instead? This would shift the concatenation onto the DB and you could pass the name as a parameter.

Comment: Yep, that will work...I'm just wondering if there's currently a way to do it in .Net Core.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug of MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.

I use [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) instead to solve the problem.